# Opentok error while trying to make 2 calls from same system

Tags: webrtc, opentok

When we tried to make more than one call from same system(desktop/mobile), opentok is giving us an error.The error is

> OT.Publisher.onStreamAvailableError SourceUnavailableError: Unknown Error while getting user media

1500 Unknown Error while getting user media

OT.exception :: title: Unable to Publish (1500) msg: Unknown Error while getting user media

SourceUnavailableError: Failed to allocate video source

The code we are using is :

```
var apiKey = 'opentok apikey';
var sessionId = 'opentok session id';
var token = 'opentok token';
var session = OT.initSession(apiKey, sessionId);
session.addEventListener('sessionConnected', sessionConnectedHandler);
session.addEventListener('sessionDisconnected', sessionDisconnectedHandler);
session.addEventListener('connectionCreated', connectionCreatedHandler);
session.addEventListener('connectionDestroyed', connectionDestroyedHandler);
session.addEventListener('streamCreated', streamCreatedHandler);
session.addEventListener('streamDestroyed', streamDestroyedHandler);
session.addEventListener('signal', signalHandler);
var parentDiv = document.getElementById('myCamera');
var publisherDiv = document.createElement('div'); // Create a div for the publisher to replace
var publisherProperties = {height: 100, width: 100};// {width:132, height:100, left: 10, top: -95};
publisherProperties.name = 'Guest';
publisherProperties.style={buttonDisplayMode: 'off'};
publisherDiv.setAttribute('id', 'opentok_publisher');
parentDiv.appendChild(publisherDiv);
var publisher = OT.initPublisher(publisherDiv.id, publisherProperties);

session.connect(token, function(error) {
session.publish(publisher);  
});
session.on('streamCreated', function(event) {

session.subscribe(event.stream,"subscribers",
                               {width:"100%", height:"100%"})
});
function sessionConnectedHandler(event) {
}
function sessionDisconnectedHandler(event) {
}
function connectionCreatedHandler(event) {

}
function connectionDestroyedHandler(event) {
}
function streamCreatedHandler(event) {
}
function streamDestroyedHandler(event) {
}
function signalHandler(event) {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am able to open meet.tokbox.com in a Chrome window and a Firefox window and successfully have a conversation with myself with full video and audio, so first of all - are you sure your current implementation is correct?

But to answer your actual question, there is no API to detect unique users cross-browser. You can assign people unique tokens based on a username portal, however, so you can tag a user.

Comment: the calls will be connected to guest users, so we can't associate tokens with them, but I will check the implementation once again.

Comment: @BalaChandra: You definitily need to check your implementation again. We are also handling guest users, but even for guests user of our system we still need tokens to connect to a TokBox session. I suggest you start reading the docs carefully, see next https://tokbox.com/opentok/concepts/token_creation.html

Comment: @MarkVeenstra We are currently assigning different session token for different call request from browsers, but if a second call is being placed from the same system in different browser, opentok is giving error

Comment: Well maybe add some code to this issue that isolates your problem. How do you create sessions, how do you generate tokens and how do all the users connect? Still there is an issue in your code. The problem you have does not exist in our code and also not in @DaveMun code.

Comment: @MarkVeenstra ok, we will check our implementation again, thanks

Comment: @MarkVeenstra I have updated the question with the error and the code we are using . Please look into it. Thanks.!

Comment: There is nothing unique in your implementation. 1500 error typically means for camera busy - meaning conflicting access to one camera.

Are you using Internet Explorer as your browser to open two windows?

Comment: @DaveMun We are using firefox and chrome, our aim is not to show this error to the end user.

Comment: Do you still see this error if you open two sessions in tokbox.com/tools/debugger ? One in Chrome and one in Firefox?